# Windows 11 DOS FOR/IF

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-11, ms-dos

I am trying to include in a batch file a check to see if a java process is already running before attempting to start it.

I have the following working command:

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %g IN ('wmic PROCESS where "name like '%java%' and CommandLine like '%surveyEngine%'" get ProcessId') DO (SET var=%g)
ECHO %var%
```

However, the `var` variable is NOT being set correctly.

When I run the initial wmic command I get three lines returned;

```
 ) Users\gavin>(SET var=ProcessId

 ) Users\gavin>(SET var=4964

 ) Users\gavin>(SET var=
```

and if I attempt to `ECHO %var%`
I get `ECHO is on` and not a value.

Can anyone see any tweaks to my command that will allow me to capture the second line?

I am not "stuck on" using wmic... I just care about is this process running, or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The `var` variable is NOT being set correctly.

Inside a batch file you needed to use 2 `%`s instead of 1.

> The operation of the `FOR` command can be summarised as...
>
> - Take a set of data
> - Make a `FOR` Parameter `%%G` equal to some part of that data
> - Perform a command (optionally using the parameter as part of the command).
> - Repeat for each item of data
>
> If you are using the FOR command at the command line rather than in a
> batch program, use just one percent sign: `%G` instead of `%%G`.

Source: [For - Looping commands - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)

To capture only the 2nd line:

```
rem skip 1st line
FOR /F "tokens=* skip=1" %%g IN ('wmic PROCESS where "name like '%java%' and CommandLine like '%surveyEngine%'" get ProcessId') DO (
    SET var=%%g
    rem finished
    goto done
    )
done:
ECHO %var%
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [For /f - Loop through command output - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)
- [goto](http://ss64.com/nt/goto.html) - Direct a batch program to jump to a labelled line.

Comment: I had to double up the % in the WHERE clause to get it working - but otherwise - thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```cmd
@echo off

for /f useback^tokens^=4^delims^=^<^> %%g in (
`%__AppDir__%wbem\wmic.exe Process where "Name like '%java%' and CommandLine like '%surveyEngine%'" get ProcessId /format:xml ^| find "VALUE"
`)do set "_var=%%~g"

echo; %_var%
```

---

> *However, the var variable is NOT being set correctly.*
> That's not right to say, in fact the variable takes on a value in the
> 1st and 2nd loop of the for output, but in the last one it
> removes the variable.
>
> ```cmd
>  SET var=ProcessId
>  SET var=4964
>  SET var=    // remove variable //
> ```

The output (encodind) of `wmic.exe` doesn't help and generates line break when using in the simple form (`get MyPizza`).
After a few tries with the different optional output formats (via command complement), I started to make use of `/format:xml` with `^| find "VALUE"` to get a line of output and not have the extra spaces and/or newlines.

When copying a `command|clip` output and pasting it into an edit, notice the additional lines:

```cmd
> wmic PROCESS where "name like '%cmd.exe%' and CommandLine like '%windows%'" get commandline|clip
```

- Output pasted into a text editor:

[image]

I suggest that you consult this question:
[WMIC command in batch outputting non UTF-8 text files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55310573/wmic-command-in-batch-outputting-non-utf-8-text-files)